# MPLAB Trace Register

Tags: mplab

I new to PIC mplab and PICs.  I developed a program that I run under the simulator and things seem to be working as expected.  Now, I'd like to record what my program is doing on port C.
I have a text script that applies stimulus.  Once things get going, I detach from that script and add a trace register entry for LATC with trigger Demand and a Trace Filename.  But nothing gets written to the file.

Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I have no idea why the above did not work.  I was able to use a PC=trigger to trace RAM locations.  I decided trace register wasn't what I wanted anyway.  In it's place, I defined a macro that captured whatever I wanted into RAM locations and did a CALL debug.  By setting a BREAKPOINT at debug, I was then able to WATCH whatever SFRs and RAM locations I wished.